# DataDog system.disk_write_time_pct / system.disk_read_time_pct

Tags: datadog

I'm trying to get DataDog to display a dashboard of system information. One piece of information is the percentage of time the system is reading/writing from the disk expressed in the metrics `system.disk.read_time_pct` and `system.disk.write_time_pct`

However, when I put this graph on my dashboard it shows some parts at well over 5000%, which clearly can't be right.

[image: Data Dog Graph Editor with preview]

As you can see from the preview above, it is showing a disk read time of 5430%. If I constrain the Y-axis to 100 it regularly goes above 100%.

I can't find anything to explain this or how to graph it properly. So, how do I properly graph `system.disk.read_time_pct` and `system.disk.write_time_pct` with DataDog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had issues with it too. The agent is most likely sending a value for 100 incorrectly as 10000 instead, as that's the highest I've seen it go. To make it usable, ensure the graph type is 'line', click "Advanced" on the metric, and make the equation `a / 100`.

I didn't find any guidance on this either in my search, but this seems to go along with what I've seen logged locally into a Windows box and watching the performance counters locally.

Comment: That certainly seems to make sense and the graph looks a lot more reasonable too.

Comment: I have observed at least one datapoint at `13,1200` :shrug:

Comment: I wonder if it's not a ratio of write-time per unit of time. Let's say the system is on its knees, thrashing a lot, and each write is taking a huge time, like 500ms to finish. Let's say each second it manage to finish 4 writes (and start 4 new ones). Then you have 4 writes, each reporting 500ms execution time, over the second. 2s per second = 200%.